# For a given timestamp find index of row in a dataframe with closest timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, closest

I have a DataFrame that is composed of 3 columns (timestamp, name, value).

The DF's rows are sorted by the timestamp in ascending order.

Given an input timestamp that may not have an identical match in the DF and a target name (which is guaranteed to be on a row).

I would like to find the index to the row where:

1. The timestamp in row is either equal to the input timestamp or
2. Is the next one less than the input timestamp and the row's name is equal to the given name.

Furthermore the timestamps in the timestamp are all unique.

Given the following DataFrame:

```
row   timestamp   name   value
0     1           A      V1
1     3           B      V2
2     5           C      V3
3     7           D      V4
4     9           A      V5
5     11          B      V6
6     13          C      V7
7     15          D      V8
```

For timestamp = 3 and name = B the index should be 1

For timestamp = 6 and name = C the index should be 2

For timestamp = 13 and name = A the index should be 4

For timestamp = 6 and name = D the index should be NaN as there is no value at or before time 6

How would this be accomplished (hopefully efficiently) in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can run query for name, sort by timestamp and grab the index of the item with the largest value if the queried dataframe isn't empty. Something like this should work.

```
def run_query(df, search_name, search_timestamp):
    query = df.loc[(df['name'] == search_name) & (df['timestamp'] <= search_timestamp)] \
              .sort_values('timestamp') 
    return None if query.empty else query.index[-1]
```